# quotient of two entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a quotient of two entire functions , i.e. $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{h(z)}$ where $f,h$ are entire functions in complex plane. If $f$ and $h$ have the same set of zeros, what can we tell from the order of these zeros? For example, if we have $f(z_0)=h(z_0)=0$, what can we say about order of $z_0$ as a zero of $h(z)$?

Also, in order for $g$ to be entire, we only need to examine how $g$ behaves at the neighbourhood of $g^{-1}(0)$. In this case, what conditions are needed so that $g$ is entire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Expand the functions $f$ and $h$ in Taylor series about $z_0$.

Comment: If we only have the above condition without '$f(z) \leq h(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$' , can we conclude $g$ is entire?

Comment: Do you mean $|f(z)| \leq |h(z)|$?  If so, then you would also have $|g(z)| \leq 1$, so that $g$ is either constant (and $f(z) = c\cdot g(z)$) or $g$ is not entire and has no poles.  But this second option is impossible, why?

Comment: Since $|g(z)| \leq 1$, $g$ has a removable singularity at $g^{-1}(0)$ and hence entire?

Comment: The symbol $g^{-1}(0)$ represents a set (unless you know that $g$ is invertible), so instead of "at $g^{-1}(0)$" it would be more accurate to say "at every $z \in g^{-1}(0)$".  Now, if $z \in g^{-1}(0)$ then $g(z) = 0$ by definition, so if you also know that $g$ is bounded then it is indeed true that either $g$ is analytic at $z$ or $z$ is a removable singularity.  But lots of non-entire functions are analytic at their zeros, so this isn't enough to tell you that $g$ is entire.

Comment: But we know that $h$ is analytic on the set $\mathbb{C} \backslash g^{-1}(0)$ (because $f$ and $g$ are entire) . If $g$ is also analytic on its zero, wouldn't it be an entire function in the complex plane?

Comment: Wait a sec, if $g = f/h$ do you know that $f$ and $h$ are entire or do you know that $f$ and $g$ are entire?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It should be $f$ and $h$ are entire.

Comment: Could you write your last question again then?  Just so we're clear.

Comment: But we know that $g$ is analytic on the set $\mathbb{C}\backslash g^{−1}(0)$ (because $f$ and $h$ are entire) . If $g$ is also analytic on its zero, wouldn't it be an entire function in the complex plane?

Comment: You *don't* know that $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus g^{-1}(0)$, even if $f$ and $h$ are entire.  Consider $f(z) = 1$, $h(z) = 1-z$.  Then $f$ and $h$ are entire but $g(z) = f(z)/h(z) = 1/(1-z)$ is *not* analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus g^{-1}(0)$ (note that $g^{-1}(0) = \emptyset$).

Comment: Or, since you want $f$ and $h$ to have the same zeros, take $f(z) = 1-z$ and $h(z) = (1-z)^2$.  Then $g(z) = 1/(1-z)$ still.

Comment: Then what about $\mathbb{C} \backslash h^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus h^{-1}(0)$, yes.